# How to override function in javascript ? casperjs then function

Tags: javascript, casperjs, overriding

I want to check if the "login page" appear before each step :

Here is my code:

```
casper.then(function() {
    checkIfRedirectedToLoginPage();
    this.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById("").click();
    });

});

casper.then(function() {
    checkIfRedirectedToLoginPage();
    this.evaluate(function() {
    });

});

function checkIfRedirectedToLoginPage(){
    if loginPage{
        this.then(function(){
             this.sendKeys(x('//*[@id="user_name"]'), USER_NAME);
             this.sendKeys(x('//*[@id="password"]'),PASSWORD);
             this.click(x(//*[@id="login"]));
        });
    }

}
```

How it's possible to override `casper.then` without littering my code with the checkIfRedirectedToLoginPage function . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible to do this though it is not recommended.  what I would suggest instead is to create a helper method that calls `casper.then` and accepts a function as a callback.

```
function myCasperThen(callback) {
    return casper.then(function() {
        checkIfRedirectedToLoginPage();
        callback();
    }
}
```